# drawing bezier blobs without intersections or bowties

Tags: graphics, processing, bezier

I'm trying to do something which appears to be rather simple (draw an animating, amoeba-like blobby shape - similar to the second image below) but which I am coming to realize has more complexity to it.

The first image below shows where I am with this:

- 6 points (instances of a simple class) which can move at random on their own within certain constraints (mainly maximum distance from a defined point on screen)
- the green dot is the dynamically calculated center of the area defined by my point instances
- I am simply drawing the vector in the array order of my point instances (a, b, c, etc)

I don't know much about vector graphics (hence this learning exercise) but I understand that I need to impose a more coherent order and set of rules on my points

- they can't cross imaginary lines between other points (b is crossing c-d below)
- they need to be chained to their immediate neighbors

I am not having a problem with code so much as needing to understand what sort of constraints I need to add - and what the specific problems/tasks are called so I can read up on them. Can anyone give me a shove in the right direction?

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are not Bezier curves or you are not showing us all the control points. You should make the control points cyclic to avoid the ugly a-f straight line.

Comment: On each iteration, find the centroid/average of all the points, then calculate the radial direction from that centroid to each point, and sort your array by that direction. That's one way, at least...

Comment: @YvesDaoust - you're right - I'm using Processing's curve/curveVertex methods which apparently are an implementation of Catmull-Rom. Went with that just because it is simpler than beziers. If I figure out my problems described above, I'll switch over to beziers - that straight line is ugly!

Comment: The "guilt" is not on the Catmull-Rom splines.

Comment: Your question is a rather uneasy one. A starting approach could be to consider the "star" formed by the bisectors of the lines from the control points to their centroid, and ensure that every control point stays confined in its own sector. This will not completely avoid curve crossings but will ensure that the hexagon does not fold.

Comment: Is drawing with a different mode possible? Most drawing packages support either "even-odd" shape fill or "non-zero winding" shape fill. You're currently using even-odd fills. If you switch to non-zero winding fills, the hole will be filled in.